# How can I protect my Gmail and Facebook account from a particular IP address?

Tags: gmail, facebook

After leaving a company, it's possible that there are traces of your account information for personal services. Is there a way to "ban" a range of IPs from ever accessing your Gmail account or Facebook account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible since you don't control the server's that Gmail and Facebook are hosted on.

HOWEVER... there is something you can do to prevent accessing your accounts from cookies, etc.

**BOTH**

- The easiest way to prevent access to browsers with possible access is to change your password. Once the password is changed, any attempt to view your logged in Gmail or Facebook account will redirect the viewer to the login page.

**GMail**

- You can turn on [2-step verification](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig) this will enable you to protect your account from any access (with valid cookies/password) because a new browser will require an authentication code that is sent to a cell phone number that you provide.
- Also, at the bottom of that page is a link to `Require a verification code the next time I log in from any other computer`

**Facebook**

- Go to your [Account Security Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&view) and look at the `Active Sessions` area. You can end the activity on each of those (you'll have to log in again) but that will require a login from each of the other machines you've access Facebook on.
- Also from that same page you can enable `Login Notifications` and `Login Approvals` for added security.

I would suggest, however, that you use the `BOTH` option that I gave originally. Good luck!